# Find and update a specific object in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am generating a form that is constructed from JSON. I've successfully created the form, but I am now trying to figure out how to update the specific item in JSON from the user input. I've seen this question asked using node and underscore, etc but I would like to accomplish this with vanilla JS or jQuery.

I am trying to avoid modifying the JSON other than the values as it will need to be sent back in the same format, and I am able to find an item by its key or value, however the problem I have is that there are multiple k/v pairs in each object that I am using. Here is an example object:

```
var list = {
"parent": {
   "item" : {
      "id" : "a1b295",
      "name" : "sample name",
      "value" : "this is a sample value"
   }
}
```

My form elements come out as `<input type="text" name="a1b295" value="this is a sample value" />`

What I am trying to do is on submit, iterate through the form elements and update each object in the JSON. I am struggling to figure out how to look up the item by its id and then update the `value` key value pair for that object.

To be clear the data can have any number of nested children, and I need to go after the ones with specific IDs which I am already turning into form inputs.

Thank you.

This is what I have attempted but it returns a "can't access id of undefined" error.

```
function traverseData(data, obj)
  {
      for (var k in data)
      {
          if (typeof data[k] == "object" && data[k] !== null) {
              traverseData(obj[k], obj);
          } else if (!data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            continue;
          } else if (k = obj) {
            console.log(obj);
          }
      }
  }

  traverseData(data, $(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Am I understanding that you want to update a JSON array (of objects in the format given above) with updated values based on the form changes when you submit the form?

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed version of your JSON? Perhaps include more than one form input object. Are there any arrays in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript now supports [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) where you can loop through object keys:

```js
let data = {
  "item" : {
     "id" : "a1b295",
     "name" : "sample name",
     "value" : "this is a sample value"
  }
};


function traverseData(data, obj, newValue)
  {
      for (var k in data)
      {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(k) && typeof data[k] == "object") {
              data[k] = traverseData(data[k], obj, newValue);
          } else if (k == obj) {
            console.log(obj);
            data[k] = newValue;
          }
      }
      return data
  }

//single element
$('input').blur(function(event){
   data = traverseData(data, 'value', $(this).attr('value'));
   console.log(data);
});

//multiple elements
$('input').each(function (index) {
   let self = $(this); //to differenciate between elements
   self.blur(function(event){
      data = traverseData(data, 'value', $(this).attr('value'));
      console.log(data);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="a1b295" value="this is a sample value 2" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated the question to be more clear as I am trying to traverse a JSON object of unknown depth. I've created a bit of a recursive function (added to the question) but am getting errors, your help would be appreciated

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, check it and let me know.

Comment: @nghs Sorry, I forgot to mention you.

Comment: that seems to work, though i changed 'input' to $(this) so I got the name for the specific form field I am working with, let me see if I can replace the `console.log` so it updates the json and I'll mark it right, thank you! If you have a quick solution for that ready just let me know, we should probably have that in the answer for future viewers

Comment: @nghs Done. As I understand. you need to update the json object from the html and that's what i did.

Comment: The only thing hanging me up is the value is coming in as undefined. I'm doing the above on a blur event `$('#container :input').blur(...` and using `let newValue = $(this).attr("value");` but it returns undefined, same for using `.value` instead of attr

Comment: @nghs I've updated it to be using the event `blur()` and it works fine. Remember that if you are calling more than one input using `:input`, then you need to use `$('#container :input').each(` to loop through then and then for each one you add the event.

Comment: @nghs I've updated my answer to include both cases.

Comment: I've got this kind of working but the end result is just the object we are updating, it isn't updating the entire JSON `data`, I feel like it might be an issue with the logic in the recursion as the target could be a child of the JSON or it could be a great-grand child, we don't know

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have your form which was generated from a JSON array in the format described above, and want to update the values in that JSON array with new values that may have changed on submission.

The following code assumes your forms have been set up properly, and the text values have been updated with the values in the HTML section.

### jQuery solution

```js
const json = [
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b295",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b296",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b297",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b298",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  }
]

for (const item in json) {
  json[item].item.value = $('input[name="' + json[item].item.id + '"]').val()
}
console.log(json)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="a1b295" value="this is a sample value" />
<input type="text" name="a1b296" value="New sample value1" />
<input type="text" name="a1b297" value="New sample value2" />
<input type="text" name="a1b298" value="New sample value3" />
```

### Vanilla Javascript solution

```js
const json = [
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b295",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b296",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b297",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "a1b298",
      "name": "sample name",
      "value": "this is a sample value"
    }
  }
]

for (const item in json) {
  json[item].item.value = document.querySelector('input[name="' + json[item].item.id + '"]').value
}
console.log(json)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="a1b295" value="this is a sample value" />
<input type="text" name="a1b296" value="New sample value1" />
<input type="text" name="a1b297" value="New sample value2" />
<input type="text" name="a1b298" value="New sample value3" />
```

These examples overwrite the value in the `json` variable that you can submit with your form. You should see that the `json` values have been updated to those in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response, I've updated the question to try to remove any confusion. The problem is the JSON can be nested any number of times so I need to be able to target the ones with IDs. I'm also trying to do this on blur of an input so should I be concerned about performance here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could before submitting to json alter the input string and change values accordingly.

If u need to compare to another JSON u could just compare values via function.

JSON is just a formated string.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array of objects. So you basically can filter this array to find the object of which the id matches the corresponding input's name. And then update this object's value property with the input value.

```
  const targetInput = document.getElementById('inputId')
  let newValue = targetInput.value
  let inputName = targetInput.name
  // We filter objects to find the one where id matches input's name
  let targetObject = objects.filter(i => i.item.id === inputName)
  targetObject[0].item.value = newValue
  console.log(targetObject)
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not have an array but perhaps it might be easier to just convert it to an array? I just don't want to lose the integrity of the JSON which is why I preferred to update it. I have updated the question for clarification.

Comment: You can use JSON.parse() method to convert JSON to a javascript object. Then update it in any way you need and convert back to a JSON with JSON.stringify